# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: spring-boot

Unfortunately, I could not able to find any issue in my bean configuration file. please help me on  that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = " http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:batch = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">  

   <import resource = "../jobs/context.xml" />  

   <bean id = "report" class = "Report" scope = "prototype" /> 
   <bean id = "itemProcessor" class = "CustomItemProcessor" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We'd love to help you, but your question isn't clear, so it's a bit hard.
What are you trying to do? What is the error? 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) out to understand how to ask a good question.

It does look like your XML isn't complete - where's the closing `beans` tag?

Comment: in second-line code beans its showing error 
cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Comment: Removing the space before `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` should solve your problem.